# Java Embedded Database h2

Tags: java, mysql, h2

i am trying to make a simple application using h2 Database. Program is working perfectly just for one time. when i am tying to insert more data, following error occurred.

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "C:/Users/ali/bookDB.mv.db". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-186]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked: nio:C:/Users/ali/bookDB.mv.db [1.4.186/7]

Code is

```
package h2_basic;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class H2_Basic {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
       try{ 
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/bookDB","test","test");
           Statement sta =  con.createStatement();
            String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE BOOKS "
            + "(bookid bigint auto_increment NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "
            + " booktitle VARCHAR(255), "
            + " bookauthor VARCHAR(255), "
            + " editiondate VARCHAR(255))";

           sta.execute(CREATE_TABLE);

           String sql = "INSERT INTO BOOKS (booktitle, bookauthor, editiondate) VALUES ('ali','ali','12')";
           sta.execute(sql);
       }catch(Exception ex)
       {
          ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: This sounds like there is a lock on your H2 database file.

Comment: I think connections are not closed. Add finally block and close the connection like `finally { con.close(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Change your JDBC URL to `jdbc:h2:~/bookDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`, as in

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/bookDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE","test","test");
```

to start H2 in [Automatic Mixed Mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode).

Comment: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "C:/Users/ali/bookDB.mv.db". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-186]

Comment: Just remove the lock file once. After that, it will work as expected.